# Can I show frames in dope sheet for rig bones not selected?

Tags: animation

I'm trying to animate a set of four bones that form a tail.  I'd like to set their keyframes so that they all align - however, I'm finding this difficult since I cannot see the frames I've set for bones once I click a different bone.  So if I set keyframes for bone #1 and then switch to bone #2, there is no indication for the locations of the frames I already set for bone #1.  Is there a way to show them?

Comment: have you disabled the Only Show Selected button (blue arrow icon) in the Dope Sheet?

Comment: No, didn't realize it was there. Thanks.